# Empty and defaulted constructor and member initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, c++14, default-constructor

Consider the following code:

```
template <class T>
struct myclass 
{
    // Select only one constructor in the following
    myclass() = default;                                 // 0
    myclass() {};                                        // 1
    myclass(): i{}, ptr{}, var{}, arr{}, vec{}, str{} {} // 2
    myclass(): i(), ptr(), var(), arr(), vec(), str() {} // 3

    // Data members
    int i;
    T* ptr;
    T var;
    std::array<int, 3> arr;
    std::vector<T> vec;
    std::string str;
};
```

And its use:

```
myclass<std::array<double, 3>> a;
myclass<std::array<double, 3>> b{};
myclass<std::array<double, 3>> c();
auto d = myclass<std::array<double, 3>>{};
auto e = myclass<std::array<double, 3>>();
```

So in total, mixing constructors/method of construction chosen, we have 4 * 5 = 20 cases: `a0, a1, a2, a3, b0, b1, b2, b3, ..., e3`. My question is :

What cases lead to initialized members (`i` is set to zero, `ptr` is set to `nullptr`, `arr` is filled with zeros) and what cases lead to uninitialized members?

Comment: Most vexing parse `myclass<std::array<double, 3>> c();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `c` is a declaration of function (vexing parse)

- a, 0, 1 are [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).
- b, d, e, 2, 3 are [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

For 2, 3, value-initialization of built-in will do a zero-initialization
2, 3 will call default constructor of `std::string`, `std::vector` (so empty)
2 will value initialize `std::array` (its element are value initialized)
3 will aggregate-initialize `std::array` which is an aggregate (value-initialization of its element, so `0` for `int`,`double`).

For 0, 1, default initialization of built-in won't initialize them
0, 1 will call default constructor of `std::string`, `std::vector` (so empty)
default initialization of `std::array` will default initialize its elements (`int` and `double` uninitialized)

For `myClass`, for 1, 2, 3:

- default-initialization calls default constructor.
- value-initialization call default constructor.

For `myClass`, for 0:

- default-initialization performs default initialization of its member.
- value-initialization performs zero initialization and then default initialization.

  So members will be initialized for 2, 3, b-0, d-0, e-0